# Scrollbar with extjs

Tags: extjs, scroll, extjs6

I would like to display a vertical scrollbar into the second fieldset but it seems that the fieldset height always adapts to its content.
The `scrollable` parameter doesn't change anything.

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    width: 800,
    height: 300,
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'foo',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }]
    }, {
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        scrollable: 'y',
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'foo',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'foo',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'foo',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'foo',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'foo',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'foo',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'foo',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'foo',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'foo',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }]
    }]
}).show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the secound fildset set `flex: 1` to get a visible scrollbar.
It will then receive the remaining height of the window container.

```js
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    width: 800,
    height: 300,
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'foo',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }]
    }, {
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        scrollable: 'y',
        flex: 1, // <---------- here
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'foo',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'foo',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'foo',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'foo',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'foo',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'foo',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'foo',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'foo',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'foo',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }]
    }]
}).show();
```